# $\mathbf{H}\mathbf{\Sigma}+\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{0}$ implying $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{0}$ for real, positive, diagonal $\mathbf{\Sigma}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, positive-semidefinite

I have a matrix equation

$$\mathbf{H}\mathbf{\Sigma}+\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{0}$$ 
where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a square real-valued diagonal matrix with strictly positive entries, $\mathbf{H}$ is (complex-valued) Hermitian, while $\mathbf{H}\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is anti-Hermitian. Is it possible for me to conclude anything about $\mathbf{H}$?

I have seen this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766953/does-abba-0-imply-ab-ba-0-when-a-is-real-semidefinite-matrix/1767013) but I am not too sure if it applies to my case as well. If it does, then would it mean that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{H}\mathbf{\Sigma} &= \mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{0}\\
\end{align}
and if I know that $\mathbf{\Sigma} \ne \mathbf{0}$, then 
$$\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{0}$$
Am I approaching this correctly?

Comment: The thread you give in your question already answers your question (especially the answer by loup blanc), doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned result does apply, but you may prove your hypothesis directly: from $H\Sigma+\Sigma H=0$, we get $h_{ij}\sigma_j+\sigma_ih_{ij}=0$. Consequently, $h_{ij}=0$ for every $(i,j)$ because $\sigma_i+\sigma_j\ne0$. Note that this is true not only for a Hermitian $H$, but for any square matrix $H$.